# Why is document returning a different document?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am making a web page reader that needs to inventory the text nodes in the document when it commences reading, because it reads each sentence down the page. So I'm "crawling" the text nodes you could say.

I have a procedure that uses `document.createTreeWalker` to take that inventory of text nodes.

I haven't figured out the pattern (I think there is one), but at one point when I use `document.body`, the document that gets pointed to is not the main page, but the document of an iframe. In my current debugging this happens to be a twitter widget, but I suppose it could be anything. This isn't a twitter question, but you can let that inform your answer if you happen to know twitter is doing something extra-ordinary to make document always go to it instead of the top document. In any case, regardless of the source, I need to get the right document.

What do I mean by the right document, you ask me? I'd say the document hosting the selected text, or if no text is selected then the top document.

But my real question is how did this happen, why is this happening? The last time I messed around with the dom was in 2009 when I wrote a web page reader in IE. Times have changed; I'm writing a Chrome extension and web pages seem 1000x more complex these days. Honestly, it's like a circus on the average web page, and most of it you don't see; it's buried beneath and lurking to trip up any robot like my reader.

I don't want to make a hard coded-rule for twitter, or any other widget. There must be a thousand such things that can end up adding / injecting themselves into the page. I literally can't get into the business of custom rules.

```
  this.LoadAllTextNodes = function () {
    this.AllTextNodes = textNodesUnder(document.body); // at some point, this document starts referring to something other than the top document. How did the definition of "document" change?
  }

  function textNodesUnder(root) {
    var textNodes = [];
    if (root.nodeType == 3)
      textNodes.push(root);
    else {
      var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(root, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, getTextElements, false);
      var node;
      while (node = treeWalker.nextNode())
        textNodes.push(node);
    }
    return textNodes; // Array
  }

  function getTextElements(node) {
    if (['SCRIPT', 'STYLE'].indexOf(node.parentNode.tagName) !== 0 && node.nodeValue !== '') //filter out script elements and empty elements 
      return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT
    else
      return NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP
  }
```

The web page I'm testing on happens to be https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/02/23/introducing-chrome-debugger-for-vs-code. The fact that the topic matter of the page deals with Chrome debugging is just a coincidence. It has no relation to the question. I'm just adding it in the event you'd like to see the source of the page.

[image: debugger showing the wrong document being referenced]

```
<iframe id="twitter-widget-0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" class="twitter-follow-button twitter-follow-button-rendered" title="Twitter Follow Button" src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets/follow_button.d59f1863bc12f58215682d9908af95aa.en.html#dnt=false&amp;id=twitter-widget-0&amp;lang=en&amp;screen_name=code&amp;show_count=true&amp;show_screen_name=true&amp;size=m&amp;time=1474137195557" style="position: static; visibility: visible; width: 191px; height: 20px;" data-screen-name="code"></iframe>
```

Comment: you can't access  cross domain iframe due to *"same origin policy"* so i don't see how you could possibly be getting another document. Provide a demo that reproduces the problem

Comment: @charlietfl, well that's not a good reason to down vote, just because you can't see. Trust me it's happening.

Comment: I didn't downvote...but i did vote to close due to no [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl, that's prohibitively difficult in this case. I can only repro on the certain web page with my whole extension code running. Then go through several steps to get the reader app into a certain state. If I could provide a minimal repro demo, I'm sure I'd spot the issue and not need to ask the question in the first place. The web page I'm testing on happens to be https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/02/23/introducing-chrome-debugger-for-vs-code, and I'll include a screen shot

Comment: I'm not sure this question warrants downvotes.

Comment: Have you tried simply storing `document.body` into a different variable on initialization, and then using that one in its place further on? Even if you get into a different context somehow (as @charlietfl already mentioned, due to SOP I have trouble seeing how this could happen as well), that variable should still point to the "original" (or throw an error, if not available in that context.)

Comment: It might also be enough, if you don't go into the else branch for everything that isn't a text node, but only if it is not an iframe as well. I think via the recursive function call at that point you are creating a new treewalker for the iframe contents, and that might mess up references to document and window after that.

Comment: @charlietfl, a chrome extension runs the content script for ~every~ window, including top and iframes. So that's how I could possibly be getting another document. I was waiting for someone who knew ***that***. And that person wasn't you. Only running a Chrome Extension reproduces that, so please reverse your vote to close. A fiddle was not going to be possible in this case.

Comment: @CBroe, as I attempted to assign the document at the entry point, I saw it already pointing at twitter! It was then I discovered the entry point is run multiple times, once for each frame, when a chrome extension loads onto a page it's hosting. My answer explains more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a chrome extension, the content scripts get run for each and every window, including the top window and all iframes. In this way, Chrome extension access trumps cross-site restrictions which a script running in a script tag may have.

This was instantiating a context for each frame which pointed the duplications of my extension code running in that frame to their respective documents, not the top window's document.

It runs the code in parallel. In my case each frame was queuing up content to be read without me knowing it, for the singleton `window.speechSynthesis` to read.

The fix was simple; just don't run in non-top windows:

```
if (window != window.top) return; // don't run in frames
```